# SQL Server 2012 -Security measures

Tags: sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012 we can use server level roles and login and we can assign permission to the login like (db reader, db writer, db owner...ect) other than this what can be implemented ?

Comment: Please read: [help/on-topic]

Comment: and nothing else matters..

Comment: @guest420420 certainly a case of "All these words I don't just say"

Comment: Manfred Radlwimmer -I Read the white paper what you sent thanks for that. But i didn't got the answer in that. I Really need to know the activity related to database sql-server support.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server job/batch queues must be reviewed regularly to detect unauthorized SQL Server job submissions.   When dealing with unauthorized SQL Server job submissions, it should be noted any unauthorized job submissions to SQL Server job/batch queues can potentially have significant effects on the overall ...
V-41395 Medium  SQL Server must be protected from unauthorized access by developers.    Applications employ the concept of least privilege for specific duties and information systems (including specific functions, ports, protocols, and services). The concept of least privilege is also ...
V-41394 Medium  SQL Server utilizing Discretionary Access Control (DAC) must enforce a policy that limits propagation of access rights. Discretionary Access Control (DAC) is based on the premise that individual users are "owners" of objects and therefore have discretion over who should be authorized to access the object and in which ...
V-41397 Medium  Administrative privileges, built-in server roles and built-in database roles must be assigned to the DBMS login accounts that require them via custom roles, and not directly.  SQL Server must employ the concept of least privilege for specific duties and information systems (including specific functions, ports, protocols, and services). The concept of least privilege is ...
V-41396 Medium  SQL Server must be protected from unauthorized access by developers on shared production/development host systems.  Applications employ the concept of least privilege for specific duties and information systems (including specific functions, ports, protocols, and services). The concept of least privilege is also ...
V-41391 Medium  SQL Server must maintain and support organization-defined security labels on information in process.    Security attributes are abstractions representing the basic properties or characteristics of an entity (e.g., subjects and objects) with respect to safeguarding information. These attributes are ...
V-60781 Medium  In a database owned by [sa], or by any other login having administrative privileges at the instance level, the database property TRUSTWORTHY must be OFF.   SQL Server's fixed (built-in) server roles, especially [sysadmin], have powerful capabilities that could cause great harm if misused, so their use must be tightly controlled. The SQL Server instance ...
V-41393 Medium  SQL Server must allow authorized users to associate security labels to information in the database. Security attributes are abstractions representing the basic properties or characteristics of an entity (e.g., subjects and objects) with respect to safeguarding information. These attributes are ...
V-41392 Medium  SQL Server must maintain and support organization-defined security labels on data in transmission.  Security attributes are abstractions representing the basic properties or characteristics of an entity (e.g., subjects and objects) with respect to safeguarding information. These attributes are ...
V-41422 Medium  SQL Server must protect against or limit the effects of the organization-defined types of Denial of Service (DoS) attacks.  Application management includes the ability to control the number of users and user sessions utilizing an application. Limiting the number of allowed users, and sessions per user, is helpful in ...
V-41421 Medium  SQL Server must prevent unauthorized and unintended information transfer via shared system resources.   The purpose of this control is to prevent information, including encrypted representations of information, produced by the actions of a prior user/role (or the actions of a process acting on behalf ...
V-41420 Medium  SQL Server must employ cryptographic mechanisms preventing the unauthorized disclosure of information at rest, unless the data is otherwise protected by alternative physical measures. This control is intended to address the confidentiality and integrity of information at rest in non-mobile devices and covers user information and system information. If the data is not encrypted or ...
V-41409 Medium  Unused database components and database objects must be removed.    Information systems are capable of providing a wide variety of functions and services. Some of the functions and services, provided by default, may not be necessary to support essential ...
V-41424 Medium  SQL Server must check the validity of data inputs.  Invalid user input occurs when a user inserts data or characters into an application’s data entry fields and the application is unprepared to process that data. This results in unanticipated ...
V-41404 Medium  SQL Server must be monitored to discover unauthorized changes to triggers.  When dealing with change control issues, it should be noted, any changes to the hardware, software, and/or firmware components of SQL Server and/or application can potentially have significant ...
V-41407 Medium  Database objects must be owned by accounts authorized for ownership.    SQL Server database ownership is a higher level privilege that grants full rights to everything in that database, including the right to grant privileges to others. SQL Server requires that the owner ...
V-41406 Medium  SQL Server must be monitored to discover unauthorized changes to stored procedures. When dealing with change control issues, it should be noted, any changes to the hardware, software, and/or firmware components of SQL Server and/or application can potentially have significant ...
V-41403 Medium  SQL Server must be monitored to discover unauthorized changes to functions. When dealing with change control issues, it should be noted, any changes to the hardware, software, and/or firmware components of SQL Server and/or application can potentially have significant ...
V-41402 Medium  SQL Server must provide audit record generation capability for organization-defined auditable events within the database.   Audit records can be generated from various components within the information system (e.g., network interface, hard disk, modem, etc.). From an application perspective, certain specific application ...
V-60671 Medium  In a database owned by a login not having administrative privileges at the instance level, the database property TRUSTWORTHY must be OFF unless required and authorized.    SQL Server's fixed (built-in) server roles, especially [sysadmin], have powerful capabilities that could cause great harm if misused, so their use must be tightly controlled. The SQL Server instance ...
V-41389 Medium  SQL Server must maintain and support organization-defined security labels on stored information.    Security attributes are abstractions representing the basic properties or characteristics of an entity (e.g., subjects and objects) with respect to safeguarding information. These attributes are ...
V-41419 Medium  The Service Master Key must be backed up, stored offline and off-site.  Backup and recovery of the Service Master Key may be critical to the complete recovery of the database. Not having this key can lead to loss of data during recovery.
V-41412 Medium  SQL Server must implement required cryptographic protections using cryptographic modules complying with applicable federal laws, Executive Orders, directives, policies, regulations, standards, and guidance.  Cryptography is only as strong as the encryption modules/algorithms employed to encrypt the data. Use of weak or untested encryption algorithms undermines the purposes of utilizing encryption to ...
V-41413 Medium  The Database Master Key encryption password must meet DoD password complexity requirements. Weak passwords may be easily guessed. When passwords are used to encrypt keys used for encryption of sensitive data, then the confidentiality of all data encrypted using that key is at risk.
V-41411 Medium  SQL Server must encrypt information stored in the database. When data is written to digital media, such as hard drives, mobile computers, external/removable hard drives, personal digital assistants, flash/thumb drives, etc., there is risk of data loss and/or ...
V-41416 Medium  Database Master Key passwords must not be stored in credentials within the database.    Storage of the Database Master Key password in a database credential allows decryption of sensitive data by privileged users who may not have a need-to-know requirement to access the data.
V-41417 Medium  Symmetric keys must use a DoD certificate to encrypt the key.   Data within the database is protected by use of encryption. The symmetric keys are critical for this process. If the symmetric keys were to be compromised the data could be disclosed to unauthorized ...
V-41415 Medium  The Database Master Key must be encrypted by the Service Master Key where required. When not encrypted by the Service Master Key, system administrators or application administrators may access and use the Database Master Key to view sensitive data that they are not authorized to ...